# Regex: How can I extract strings from "*" to "*"

Tags: regex

I used Sysinternals Strings to output all strings from a memory dump. I need to extract all strings from * to *.

Between the two * are domains or elements of domains (Target list of a trojan).

```
*/cmserver/*

*/pub/html/*

*arabi-online.net/efs/servlet/efs/*

*ibanking.*.com.au/InternetBanking/*
```

I tried this...but I've problems with the $ character:

```
cat strings.txt | grep -o '\*[^"]*' | egrep "[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/]{4}\*$" | sort -u
```

Comment: What kind of problems with the `$` character?

Comment: A lot of lines end with the star, but the backslash*$ doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If your grep supports PCRE, this should be easy:

```
grep -Po "(?<=\*)(.*)(?=\*)" strings.txt
```

**Input:**

```
$ cat strings.txt 
*/cmserver/*

*/pub/html/*

*arabi-online.net/efs/servlet/efs/*

*ibanking.*.com.au/InternetBanking/*
```

**Output:**

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=\*)(.*)(?=\*)" strings.txt
/cmserver/
/pub/html/
arabi-online.net/efs/servlet/efs/
ibanking.*.com.au/InternetBanking/
```

Comment: Looks pretty good, but the stars are gone...and some crap to filter is left. RAM ;-)

Comment: @user3022917 - Whatever dude, ask one question then expect an answer to a different question. You clearly do not understand how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed it is easier:

```
sed 's/^\*\|\*$//g' strings.txt
```

Comment: My strings.txt is nearly 200 MB...I've thousands of lines in the output with 3-4 letters

Comment: `.I've thousands of lines in the output with 3-4 letters ` this comment is not making much sense. I have provided you a working demo. Try to provide a sample input for which this answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat strings.txt | grep "^\*" | grep "[A-Za-z0-9\-\+\.\/]\{4\}\*.$" | sort -u works the best for me!
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. Useless use of two chained `grep`s.